# Is it possible for ThingSpeak to show a simple table of all data collected?

Tags: datalogging

I just recently found the ThingSpeak platform for the IoT. I have been playing around with its features a bit, but I have not found a way for it to show a simple table of all the data collected. For example, the table might have humidity, temperature, and timestamp columns, and then every time data is written to ThingSpeak, a new row would be added with the latest readings. I would be surprised if this is not possible with all of its complex graphing tools. Has anybody found a feature like this?

Comment: What does this have to do with the Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ThingSpeak has an extensive API, you can build a tool to read in data and display it as a table. I have created a GitHub repo called, "[IoT Debugger](https://github.com/nothans/iot-debugger)" that allows you to see data as a table as the it comes into a ThingSpeak Channel.

To use the demo, enter your channel number and the read API key.

If you want to modify the project, fork the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/nothans/iot-debugger).